# How to test outside click event functionality for React using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which detect outside Click which is implemented like this https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f

and i am using that component for Dropdown component so that it must close on outside click.

I followed this comment to unit test it but still no luck.
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426#issuecomment-431195329

outside click is not been captured please help me with this.

My test case is like this

```
it("should check outside click", () => {
    const outerNode = document.createElement('div');
    outerNode.className = "outerDiv";
    document.body.appendChild(outerNode);
    wrapper = mount(<Dropdown {...props}>{props.children}</Dropdown>, { attachTo: outerNode })
    const obj = wrapper.find("button")
    obj.instance().dispatchEvent(new Event('click', { bubbles: true }));
    expect(wrapper.state().activated).toBe(true);
    outerNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('click', { bubbles: true })); // this is not working as expected
    expect(wrapper.state().activated).toBe(false);
}
```

outside element click is not dispatched.

Comment: The question doesn't contain the code for Dropdown. Please, post it. The question should be intelligible without navigating to external links. Moreover, the article doesn't contain full code for the component, too.